# joining records from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

i tried to join records from two tables which have the following schema

```
users
----
name
phone
email

sales
----
seller_id
buyer_id
amt
date
```

here is my sql

```
Select
  sales.amt,
  sales.date,
  buyer.phone as buyer_phone,
  buyer.name as buyer_name,
  buyer.email as buyer_email,
  seller.phone As seller_phone,
  seller.name As seller_name,
  seller.email As seller_email
From
  users borrower Inner Join
  sales On borrower.id = sales.buyer_id Inner Join
  users seller On seller.id = sales.seller_id
```

but i get an empty record

the expected output is suppose to be

```
amt,
date,
buyer_phone,
buyer_name,
buyer_email,
seller_phone,
seller_name,
seller_email
```

any help or suggestion

Comment: Does your users table have an id column? You don't show it in your post.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a user.id column and that it is used as a foreign key in sales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You current query is correct if the two columns of table `sales` that will be used to join table `user` are not nullable. However, if they are nullable, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT sales.amt,
       sales.date,
       buyer.phone as buyer_phone,
       buyer.name as buyer_name,
       buyer.email as buyer_email,
       seller.phone As seller_phone,
       seller.name As seller_name,
       seller.email As seller_email
FROM   sales
       LEFT JOIN users borrower 
          ON borrower.id = sales.buyer_id 
       LEFT JOIN users seller 
          ON seller.id = sales.seller_id
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I have the feeling though that you can't have a sale without both a user and seller. So, if it's not the issue if null entries, it seems like something else is going on... e.g. IDs in sales are not the same as IDs in Users.